# Get whole output stream from remote machine after running .rb file using ssh

Tags: ruby, git, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to run rspec tests on remote machines. Before running, I need to pull from git all projects on remote machine and only then run tests. To do that I'm running terminal command, like

> ssh teststand1@192.168.0.102 "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; cd
>   (PathToProjectFolder) && git pull && git checkout develop && git pull
>   && rspec (PathToSpec)" > LOG.txt

Some messages and errors, like

> Already on 'develop'

or

> fatal: Unable to create 'path_to_somefile': File exists.

or any Ruby exceptions doesn't output to LOG.txt. I could see them in terminal, but not in LOG.txt. How can I catch them?

Comment: Most likely that output is written to `stderr`, not to `stdout`. You have to redirect that too.